# Creating overlays on mapview based on user location

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, google-geocoder

I'm trying to create an application that will display all restaurants within the users location.  The location will be obtained from the GPS.  The problem I am having is it would be unfathomable to create OverlayItems manually for all the possible restaurants in the United States.  Did I look over something in the API? I would think that there might be something like this built in.

I thought the Geocoder would be useful, I could get the coordinates from the addresses of restaurants and write methods to create overlay items out of that information, but I would still be missing information such as restaurant name.  I'm just looking for suggestions or ideas.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [SimpleGeo](http://www.simplegeo.com) service for getting the restaurant data and then using this class: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons to add items to the Google map.

What else are you looking for?

Comment: Thats perfect, I have implemented a few projects using google Map api so that shouldn't be a problem.  I just checked out the SimpleGeo service and it honestly looks to be exactly what I need.  I will post again if I have any questions about implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Abhinav I began looking at the documentation, I am having trouble figuring it out.  I plan on developing for the Android OS, but I can't find any tutorials on their website or online.

Comment: @michael What tutorials are you looking for? The Android website has lots of tutorials about all the basic stuff to create applications. Here is a good tutorial on adding Google Maps: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: @Abhinav, I was wondering if there were any about integrating SimpleGeo into an application.  When I said "their" website I meant SimpleGeo's, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Ah. They do not seem to have Java/Android tutorials. The process is quite simple though. The API returns JSON based responses to HTTP requests. All these classes are available in the Android platform. What you would have to do is - 1. Send a proper HTTP request to a SimpleGeo endpoint. 2. Receive the response and parse it using one of the Android libraries or something like Gson. 3. Display the data in your application.

Comment: @Abhinav, thanks this worked perfectly.  I didn't use the example Google Maps class you gave me, I already had one from a different project I was working on and just modified it.  Thanks again.